# Who decides the conditions on the IMF loans?

Tags: macroeconomics, imf

On one hand, I've seen a statement where the IMF states that the conditions to a loan is to designed by the government. However, in a paper I've seen that the IMF enforces conditions. Is one of the information not relevant anymore or is there anything else here?

Comment: Design and enforcement are two different things and in no way need to be done by the same party, could you clarify what the question is?

Comment: Thanks for answering. Lemme try to clarify. Does the IMF come up with the set of conditions or do the government present the set of conditions?

Comment: @JiminyCricket. I forgot to mention you in the comment.

Comment: I don't have a full answer, but it seems to me that there is some negotiation involved, at least according to the [IMF website](https://www.imf.org/en/News/Articles/2015/09/28/04/53/sopol112508a). That doesn't, of course preclude the possibility that they have a set of off-the-shelf standard approaches to situations. I'll let someone more knowledgeable chime-in.

Comment: @JiminyCricket. Thank you very much